# Point wise convergence and $\lim \int f_n=\int f<\infty$ imply $\int_E f=\lim \int_E f_n$, with $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^+, \mu(\Omega)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space, with $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$. Let $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^+$, and $$\lim f_n=f, \quad\lim \int f_n=\int f<\infty$$ then for any measurable set $E$, we have $$\lim \int_E f=\int_E f.$$

We know that $$\int_E f\leq \liminf \int_E f_n $$
by Fatou's lemma, then we just need to show that $$\limsup \int_E f_n\leq \int_E f$$
that is to say $$ \forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N},\ s.t.\ n\geq N\ \Rightarrow \ \int_E f_n\leq \int_E f+\varepsilon.$$
Since $\int f<\infty$, we have $\{f=\infty\}$ has measure zero, therefore, for sufficiently large  $n, \ \int f_n<\infty$, thus $\{f_n=\infty\}$ has measure zero. We may assume that $f_n,f$ take finite values.

What should I do next? Any hint would be appreciated
.

Comment: generalized DCT implies $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, and then your claim follows from DCT.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, we can go the other way.

Consider the functions $f-(f-f_n)^+$, we have
$$0\leq f-(f-f_n)^+\overset{p.w.}{\longrightarrow}f$$
Fatou's lemma implies that
$$\int f\leq \liminf \int\bigl(f-(f-f_n)^+\bigr)$$
$$\Rightarrow \limsup \int(f-f_n)^+\leq 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim \int (f-f_n)^+=0$$
(Notice that $\int f<\infty$)

Since $\lim \int (f-f_n)=0$, we have $$\lim\int (f-f_n)^- =0$$
therefore $$\lim \int|f-f_n|=0$$ which implies that
$$\Rightarrow \lim \int_E |f-f_n|=0.$$